# Cannot invoke AWS lambda from Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've created aws lambda following this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/run-serverless-code/). I also added the Function URL, like so:

[image]

But still getting 502 when invoking GET from postman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got 502 because your lambda throws an exception, why?

Because, when you call your lambda by Function URL, the event look like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "routeKey": "$default",
    "rawPath": "/",
    "rawQueryString": "",
    "headers": {
        "content-length": "29",
        "x-amzn-tls-version": "TLSv1.2",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
        "postman-token": "d03ad219-b9e8-4244-aa88-b54f50719646",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-forwarded-for": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "x-amzn-tls-cipher-suite": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "host": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.lambda-url.eu-west-1.on.aws",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.30.1"
    },
    "requestContext": {
        "accountId": "anonymous",
        "apiId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "domainName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.lambda-url.eu-west-1.on.aws",
        "domainPrefix": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "http": {
            "method": "POST",
            "path": "/",
            "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
            "sourceIp": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
            "userAgent": "PostmanRuntime/7.30.1"
        },
        "requestId": "xxxxx-1af5-499d-8c92-6ad760af0194",
        "routeKey": "$default",
        "stage": "$default",
        "time": "21/Feb/2023:18:55:42 +0000",
        "timeEpoch": 1677005742699
    },
    "body": "{\r\n    \"text1\":\"helloword\"\r\n}",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

and not:

```
{
  "key1": "Test",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

In this case, you have to **adapt** your code to extract the values you want.

Note: always use CloudWatch to verify what happens in your code, for example:

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'key1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 8, in lambda_handler
    print("value1 = " + event['key1'])
```

Maybe you ask how I got the payload, I just used:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    r = json.dumps(event)
    return r
```

Comment: Ah, your right, my first hour with aws.. Couldn't find blueprint/starter "Hello world lambda" in java..only node/python.. Thank you will play around. Hopefully I'll hit appropriate payload.

Comment: You can create your own, there are many tuturial on youtube

Comment: Hm, not sure how did you actually get the payload that needs to go to postman json body. If I configure under 'Test' -> 'Configure test event' and add some dummy json, the output of `r` is that dummy json and not that long payload. `context` is an instance of LambdaContext, not sure if that object can help me to construct that big object from your answer. Any help is welcome.

Comment: You said I call my lambda from the postman, I just create a sample query for example `curl --location --request POST 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.lambda-url.eu-west-1.on.aws/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "text1":"helloword"
}'` so I got back that payload on postman

Comment: As I said the Lambda Test and Postman send different things to your function.

Comment: Hm, interesting, I also managed to get that payload now. I did this, since I'm on windows: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.lambda-url.eu-central-1.on.aws/ -d "{\"TEST\":\"TEST\"}"`  Why is `r` just a simple json that we set 'Configure test event' when we call lambda from Test from aws console and on the other hand `r` is that big object when we curl lambda? What made you think to curl lambda in the first place?